# How to access windows shared folder in xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I made my folder shared and got a path from that
declare the image class in xaml like this:

```
<Image x:Name="yogin"/>
```

in code behind i am trying to access :

```
 yogin.Source = "\\path\foldername\original.jpg";
```

but image is not displaying

Comment: in xaml i am simply giving id like this:<Image x:Name="yogin"/>

Comment: "Local" Images must be contained within the app package: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/

Comment: Have you tried with yogin.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("\path\foldername\original.jpg"); ?